# Can I change the Font of ListFormat.ListString?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I can change the Font of my entire Document except the Number before a heading. I did not find any way of changing this value.
Is there any way to change the Font of the number as well, without changing it manually afterwards?

```
Word.Application wordapp = new Word.Application();

wordapp.Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri";
```

This Code changes the Font of my entire Document but does not change the Font of the Numbering infront of a heading.
This is just an example I know that I have to add the document to my WordApp aswell.

Comment: Please add a [minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tackling formatting in a document it's very important to learn about Word **Styles**. Just selecting a document's content and applying font formatting is *not* the correct way to create a robust, professional document.

By installation default, every new document has some one hundred styles embedded in it - "built-in styles". Styles can base on other styles (similar to CSS) - the style that almost all other styles base on is "Normal". So changing the characteristics of "Normal" will change all other styles that base on it, unless that characteristic/attribute/property has specifically been set differently.

To change the font name and size for all "plain" text in the document, including the numbering use something like this:

```
Document.Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal].Font.Name = "Calibri";
Document.Styles[Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal].Font.Size = 14f;
```